# Any way to set alerts if logstash is not sending data

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elasticsearch-plugin

Is there any service or tool or setup that will help me to set up alerts if logstash is not sending data to the elasticsearch?
Can cloudwatch-aws can be customized for that or there is any policy in new relic or any other tool that would help?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a [statsd](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-statsd.html) or [graphite](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-graphite.html) output to your Logstash pipeline and hook it up to [lovebeat](https://github.com/boivie/lovebeat), which detects anomalies in the frequency of messages. It can then notify you of such changes via email or you can use an external alerting engine to query lovebeat's state via REST.

Comment: Won't this be too much to manage. I was thinking that it would be great if anyhow it can be integrated with aws cloudwatch or newrelic so that there would be no more tools to manage.

Comment: You shouldn't have any problems integrating lovebeat with Cloudwatch or New Relic. I don't know them well enough to determine whether the latter two have a built-in way of alerting if they don't receive continuous stimuli from Logstash, but if they do that would certainly be an option.